# JSON for Objective-C returns error "Illegal start of token [r]"

Tags: objective-c, json, xcode4

I am attempting to connect to a web page and return a JSON string. This string simply needs to be parsed in JSON and returned into an NSArray that I have waiting for it. The problem is that JSON doesn't always return the results. Sometimes, it works well. Sometimes, it returns (null), citing the error below.

```
self.accounts = nil; // Clear the NSArray

NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@", username.text];
NSData *postData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [post UTF8String] length: [post length]];

// Submit login data
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://###.#####.###/app/getaccts.php"]];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setValue: @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody: postData];

// Retreive server response
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[returnData bytes]];

accounts = [[content JSONValue] allValues]; // Parse JSON string into the array
NSLog(@"Array: %@", accounts);
```

The page I am submitting to returns this:

```
{"1":"856069060", "2":"856056407"}
```

JSON logs the following error:

```
-JSONValue failed. Error is: Illegal start of token [r]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can I get a little more info ... specifically, I'd like you to check the return value of your sendSynchronousRequest so can you make this change and rerun your test:

```
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
if (returnData == nil) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", err);
} else {
    NSLog(@"DATA: %@", returnData);
}
```

Comment: Ok, I added what you asked and returnData returned this:
<7b223122 3a223835 36303639 30363022 2c202232 223a2238 35363035 36343037 227d>

JSON didn't trigger the same error this time. It behaves unusually inconsistent.

Comment: I tried once more a minute ago and returnData returned what you see in my last comment and now JSON returns "Illegal start of token [s]". I can't figure out why JSON is receiving the data, but won't parse it.

Comment: Cool, yeah, the issue is -[NSString stringWithUTF8String:] expects a true UTF8 string and yours is not because it's not NULL terminated (since the returnData doesn't finish with a 00). Make sure you add a NULL character to the end of your string and you should be fine.

Comment: So I need to go to my PHP page that is returning the JSON string and concat char(0) on the end of it? Will that terminate the string properly?

Comment: Yes that will work ... although it still leaves your app vulnerable to malformed JSON. For security reasons, it would be best if in addition to that, you also added a NULL character to the end of any JSON you receive if one isn't there, or just throw away JSON you receive that doesn't finish with a NULL character.

Comment: You'll have to pardon me if I'm a bit new to Obj-C. What does a NULL char look like in Obj-C?

Comment: It's the same in C/C++/ObjC ... it's just '\0', which evaluated to 0.