# -JSONValue failed. Error is: Illegal start of token [']

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, parsing

I have json string from here: http://vkontakte.ru/al_video.php?act=load_videos_silent&al=1&oid=8046830

I use Touch json parser.

```
//received json string from ASIHTTPRequest
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
//removing all html elements like "br"
NSString *jsonString = [self decodeHTMLEntities:responseString];
//remove 4830<!><!>0<!>4316<!>0<!> this string at the beginning
jsonString = [jsonString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 25) withString:@""];
NSArray *arr = [jsonString JSONValue]
//And here is an error in Debug console: -JSONValue failed. Error is: Illegal start of token [']
```

How to solve this?

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834591/json-for-objective-c-returns-error-illegal-start-of-token-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to replace all the ' by ". JSON usually doesn't support ' as a token delimitor.

use :

```
jsonString = [jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""];
jsonString = [jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"\""];
```

Comment: Zoleas, i've this quotes in some words (

Comment: This.  Or fix your stream.  Single quotes are not supported.

Comment: You can first replace all your " by \" then all your ' by ". I'll edit my post

Comment: After replacing all ' by " with textEdit, the json seems valid. I validate it without any problem on jsonlint.com and in textmate with the JSON Bundle.